# "Open In Terminal" action in Nautilus in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: nautilus, 14.04

I've gotten used to the "Open In Terminal" option when right clicking in Nautilus.  I used it a lot in 12.04, but it seems to have disappeared in 14.04.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
[...]
$ sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nautilus-open-terminal
$ sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nautilus-actions
```

How do I get this feature in 14.04?